# Possible combinations of colours

Tags: colors

Say I have a list of 2 colours, Black and White. It's only possible to have 1 combination using these colours, because you can't have two of the same.

If I have 3 colours (Black, White and Red), there are 3 possible combination (Black+White, Black+Red, White+Red).

If I have 4 colours, there are 5 possible combinations and if I have 5 colours there are 10 possible combinations.

I'm trying to work out the relationship between the number of colours and the possible combinations. Here is some data:

Colours Combinations

0 0

1 0

2 1

3 3

4 5

5 10

6 14

Comment: While I'm sure there are people here happy to indulge you with an answer, this kind of question is probably better suited for http://www.mathoverflow.com

Comment: You seem to have a bug in your counting. Answer is n choose 2 = n(n-1)/2. 4 choose 2 is 6 (not 5). 6 choose 2 is 15 (not 14). Also, this is off-topic, either here or on mathoverflow.

Comment: @Jamie: You got to be kidding, right? This question will be kicked from there faster than you can ask it. The *math* in mathoverflow doesn't refer to *school* problems but rather problems PhD candidates are pondering. That's ... a few levels away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

The formula for the number of pairs from a set of size n is `n * (n - 1) / 2`.

Your values are incorrect. The correct values are:

```
n   nCr (r=2)
2   1
3   3
4   6
5   10
6   15
```

This sequence is also known as the [triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Comment: Thank you so much! You are right, my values were incorrect. I did double check them, but somehow made the same mistake twice.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

The formula to calculate the value is:

`(n!)/(k!(n-k)!)`

Where n is the total amount of possible colors and k is how many colors will you pick, so

`"1 out of 3" = 3! / 1!*2! => 3*2*1/1*2*1 = 3`

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

[Combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of `num_colors` taken `2` at a time:

```
C(n, k) = n!/(k!*(n - k!))

C(0, 2) = C(1, 2) = 0 by definition in your case
C(2, 2) = 2!/(2!*0!) = 2!/2! = 1 (0! is usually 1)
C(6, 2) = 6!/(2!*4!) = 15 (is your 14 a mistake?)
```

This simplifies to `n*(n - 1) / 2` when `k = 2`.